# PHP Facebook Tagging user in app photo

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I am trying to tag my facebook-app user in the photo created by the app. but its giving me error.

```
$args = array(
   'message' => $fbme['name'].' will have a love marriage.',
   'image'   => '@' . realpath('./images/wall-e-and-eva1.jpg'),
   'tags'    => array(
                   array(
                       'tag_uid'=> $uid,
                       'x'      => 0,
                       'y'      => 0,
                   )
                )
);

$data = $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/photos', 'post', $args);
```

where

```
$uid =$facebook->getUser();
```

I am getting the below error. I dont understand how the photo is created and uploaded to user profile but user name is not tagged to it.

`ERROR:- Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#121) Invalid photo id thrown in /home/a2611469/public_html/myweb/src/facebook.php on line 543`

Thanks in advance

Comment: just a question - have you enabled the `$setFileUploadSupport` to true in your facebook php sdk?

Comment: @Lix I have {
     include_once "src/facebook.php";
     $app_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
     $application_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
     $facebook = new Facebook(array(
     'appId'  => $app_id,
     'fileUpload' =>true,
     'secret' => $application_secret,
     'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
     ));}
fileupload=true here on each page. Is it right?

Comment: well when ever you want to upload a picture you have to set that value.  Can you upload the picture with out tags?

Comment: Lix even when I used $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true); the tag is not working. Yes I am able to upload the picture without tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're supposed to POST photo tags to "/$photo_id/tags/$user_id", not to /$uid/photos which is the way you do it. You might have to do one separate API request for each tag, after uploading the actual photo.

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Comment: I added these 2 lines to the above code right after $data api call. still not working. Please help. Thank You.

Comment: Post the image to Facebook without using the "tags" subarray. Check $data['id'] to get the id of the uploaded photo.

Then tag the photo this way:

`$response = $facebook->api(
        "/$photo_id/tags/$person_id",
        'POST',
        array(
            'x' => $x-coord,
            'y' => $y-coord,
        )
    );`

Comment: Thank you @ Janek that helped me. +1 for you